# Heatmap.2 Color Key Is Not Showing Up

Tags: r, heatmap

I was trying to draw a heatmap.2 from RStudio. However, the color key disappeared starting from one point and I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
ghe <- read.csv("greenhouse-emissions.csv")

gh_df <- ghe[ghe$Pollutant == "Greenhouse gases",]
gh_df <- gh_df[gh_df$VAR == "TOTAL", ]

cyv_df <- gh_df[c('Country', 'Year', 'Value')]
cyv_df <- cyv_df[cyv_df$Country != "OECD - Total",]

new_df <- cyv_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Value)

new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- 0

#Creating matrix for heatmap.2
m <- data.matrix(new_df)
m <- m[,-1]

# My original color palette. However, I later decided to not use the palette because I thought the palette was the cause behind the color key disappearance.
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("mintcream",
                                 "cadetblue",
                                 "darkolivegreen1",
                                 "yellow", 
                                 "tan1",
                                 #"darkgoldenrod",
                                 "red",
                                 "red2",
                                 "red4",
                                 "black"))(99)

col_breaks = c(seq(-1, 1, length=1),
               seq(1.001, 3428.207,length=5),
               seq(3428.208, 61257.344, length=15),
               seq(61257.345, 592587.216,length=10), #upper smaller countries
               seq(592587.217, 1.27e+06, length=19), #Germany
               seq(1270000.001, 1.33e+06, length=19),# Japan
               seq(1330000.001, 2.5e+06,length=11), # Russia
               seq(2500000.001, 6.25e+06, length=10),
               seq(6250000.001, 17124526.000, length=10))

Colors=rev(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"))
Colors=colorRampPalette(Colors)(99)

dev.off()
heatmap.2(m,
          col=Colors, 
          breaks=col_breaks,
          trace="none", 
          Colv=NA, 
          # Rowv = NA,
          dendrogram = 'none',
          margins=c(5,5),
          density.info='histogram', 
          denscol="black",
          key=TRUE,
          symkey=FALSE,
          keysize=1, 
          key.par=list(mar=c(3.5,0,3,0)),
          lmat=rbind(c(5, 4, 2), c(6, 1, 3)), 
          lwid=c(1, 10, 1),
          notecol = 'black')
```

I tried switching from my own color palette to a default one that already exists. I've also commented out the lines related to margins hoping to solve the problem - to no avail.

Comment: What is `m`? We can't run your code to test or verify solutions without this.

Comment: Just edited! m is the dataframed turned into matrix for heatmap.2